# "all placeholder ndarrays should have been allocated" with jax-metal using jaxopt

Tags: macos, jax

I'm able to run other code like `optax` on my Macbook Pro M3 GPU just fine, but I haven't been able to get `jaxopt` working. I'm trying to run this simple code:

```py
from jax import numpy as jnp
from jaxopt import LBFGS

def loss(x):
  return x**2

opt = LBFGS(loss)
print(opt.run(jnp.array(3.0)))
```

But it gives this error:

```
/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/mpsgraph/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/Runtimes/MPSRuntime/MPSRuntime.mm:1422:
failed assertion `MPSGraphKernelDAG: all placeholder ndarrays should have been allocated'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a `jax-metal` bug? They do loudly warn that `JAX Apple GPU support is experimental and not all JAX functionality is correctly supported!` after all.

Comment: JAX-metal is experimental and still quite incomplete, so these kinds of bugs would not be unexpected.

Comment: Yeah, I tried some other stuff out and it works on CPU, so I'm pretty confident this is a jax-metal bug now. I also realized my workload runs 300x faster on the CPU, even though it's extremely parallel, so not sure what jax-metal is doing wrong.